# CSS for Firefox The text in Helvetica is somewhat higher than in other browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

Please see this minimum example:

```css
span {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<span>1299</span>
```

Screenshot:

## Chrome

[image]

## Firefox

[image]

As you can see, Firefox renders the typeface a little taller; why is this?

Is it possible to make Firefox look like Chrome?

## Update

Adding `line-height` and `display: inline-block` makes the red container same height, but the font position remains incorrect, please see this minimum example:

```css
span {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span>1299</span>
```

[image]

Comment: the rendered fontsize seems similar.. but probably they have a different line-height in the computed values? do you want to try to set it manually in your css rule? also try to set `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Hi @DiegoDeVita, I've updated the post, can you take a look?

Comment: you should try playing with other css properties to see if you can make them as equal as possible. It's a matter of trial and error... I can see for example that the firefox sample is shifted downwards compared to the chrome one (there's a spacing between red border and the gray reference line and the border-bottom is a bit cropped). But it makes the situation more severe because the FF span has a higher baseline. I would try being explicit with everything starting from the padding-bottom

Comment: as a side note.. each browser has its own default value for some css properties according to the element type. There are css libraries that make sure to reset the browser defaults with very general rules like: `*,*::after,*::before{/*explicit default style*/}` or `div{} span{} p{}` and so on.. so being explicit with your css will make sure those defaults are not involved in the differences you see in the render. **Anyway I would also use a real unit on your line-height.. like using px**

Comment: I used to have a CSS reset on my website, but I removed it to address the problem.
I haven't yet discovered a property that may make them appear identical.